# Database Permission Structure

Tags: sql-server, performance, permissions, database-permissions

Many of my employers applications share a similar internal permission structure for restricting data to a specific set of users or groups. Groups can also be nested.

The problem we're currently facing with this approach is that enumerating the permissions is incredibly slow. The current method uses a stored procedure with many cursors and temporary tables. This has worked fine for smaller applications, but we now have one particular system which is growing quickly, and it's starting to slow down.

The basic table structure is as follows;

**tblUser** { UserID, Username, WindowsLogonName }

**tblGroup** { GroupID, Name, Description, SystemFlag }

**tblGroupGroup** { GroupGroupID, Name, }

**tblGroupUser** { GroupUserID, Name, }

and to tie it all together;

**tblPermission** { PermissionID, SecurityObjectID, SecuredID, TableName, AllowFlag }

which contains rows like..

'5255-5152-1234-5678', '{ID of a Group}', '{ID for something in tblJob}', 'tblJob', 1

'4240-7678-5435-8774', '{ID of a User}', '{ID for something in tblJob}', 'tblJob', 1

'5434-2424-5244-5678', '{ID of a Group}', '{ID for something in tblTask}', 'tblTask', 0

**Surely there must be a more efficient approach to enumerating all the groups, and getting the ID's of the secured rows?**

To complicate things further; if a user is explicitly denied access to a row then this overrules any group permissions. This is all in MSSQL.

Comment: What version of SQL server are you using; have a couple of suggestions but they depend on the version of sql server. 

Take a look at the finalized permissions in the higher load app you might be able to split the checks to grant and deny on your select which may simplify the execution as I am used to seeing more grants than denys in my apps.

Comment: SQL Server 2005. Where can I find information on the 'higher load app'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing it would be useful to break apart tblPermission into a couple of tables: one for groups and one for users.  By having both groups and users in there, it seems to add complexity to the design (and maybe that's why you need the stored procedures).

If you want to break down the tblPermission table (into something like tblUserPermission and tblGroupPermission) but still want a representation of the tables that looks like tblPermission, you can make a view that union's the data from the two tables.

Hope this helps.  Do you have examples of what the stored procedures do?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, although I think splitting out User and Group permissions would complicate things even further since permissions are always calculated on user and group basis. We also have a reasonably well defined object model that expects things in certain places.

I've put together this script which seems to work well at enumerating the permissions; http://pastebin.com/f3877c416
In a few tests it returns the same number of rows as the current stored procedures, but in <1 second instead of 30.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use a [Recursive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx) Common Table Expressions ([CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx)) hierarchical query. You can find many examples if you search for it. [This](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1520) is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your design is OK, but the implementation/code is wrong.

Some thoughts:

- Are all your ID columns GUID? Not recommended [Kimberley L Tripp article](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/GUIDs-as-PRIMARY-KEYs-andor-the-clustering-key.aspx)
- Indexes on all foreign keys, perhaps with other columns in key or INCLUDE
- Regular maintenance? eg fragmented indexes, stats ot of date etc
- Are all datatypes matching (assumes no FKs): datatype precedence and implicit conversion errors may creep in

Some more schema info and examples of poorly performing code may help